# Firebase storage amount of free memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to get the amount of free memory in the section *storage* of **Firebase**?
I want to display the free memory space bar on the page.

Comment: or is there only one way to use .map for all file.size and count the dimensions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. Are you trying to measure how much space is left between your current database size and the quota of your project?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, in my application I want to monitor and display the limit of available memory for uploads and to catch errors in exceeding the limit